# Как вытащить из строки дату и отсчитать от неё время до сегодняшнего дня в годах?

Tags: python, datetime

Есть строка `'31/07/1972 (45 years old)'`. Хочу вытащить из неё либо возраст `45`, либо запарсить дату `31/07/1972` и определить по ней возраст человека. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

```
In [114]: import re

In [115]: s = '31/07/1972 (45 years old)'

In [116]: g = re.search(r'[^\s]*\s+\(\s*(\d+)\s*.*', s).groups()

In [117]: age = int(g[0]) if g else -1

In [118]: print(age)
45

In [119]: type(age)
Out[119]: int
```

Чтобы посчитать возраст:

```
from datetime import datetime

def parse_date(s, fmt='%d/%m/%Y'):
    d = s.split()[0]
    return datetime.strptime(d, fmt)

def calc_age(d):
    today = datetime.today()
    return today.year - d.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (d.month, d.day))
```

Примеры:

```
In [199]: d = parse_date(s)

In [200]: d
Out[200]: datetime.datetime(1972, 7, 31, 0, 0)

In [201]: calc_age(d)
Out[201]: 45

In [202]: calc_age(parse_date(s))
Out[202]: 45

In [203]: calc_age(parse_date('1985-12-30', fmt='%Y-%m-%d'))
Out[203]: 31
```

`s.split()` - разбивает строку по пробелам в список:

```
In [132]: s.split()
Out[132]: ['31/07/1972', '(45', 'years', 'old)']
```

т.е. чтобы получить дату - берем первый (index=0) элемент списка:

```
In [133]: s.split()[0]
Out[133]: '31/07/1972'
```

Comment: Когда писал свой ответ у вас `еще` не было с datetime, зато у меня проще выглядит пример ;)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вытащить возраст напрямую:

```
import re

text  = '31/07/1972 (45 years old)'
age = int(re.search(r"\((\d+)\s+years\s+old\)", text).group(1))
print(age)  # -> 45
```

Чтобы дату вытащить, если строка всегда с даты в указанном формате начинается:

```
from datetime import date

date_str, _ = text.split(None, 1)
birthday = date(*map(int, date_str.split('/')[::-1]))
assert birthday == datetime.strptime("%d/%m/%Y", date_str).date()
```

Чтобы возраст в годах найти с учётом високосных лет:

```
def years(now, then):
    return (now.year - then.year) - (now < then.replace(year=now.year))

age = years(date.today(), birthday)
print(age)  # -> 45
```

Если день рождения на 29 февраля приходится, то ошибка выбрасывается, чтобы явно выбор сделать:

- если на 1 марта в обычные годы переносится, то можно сравнение заменить на:

  ```
  (now.month, now.day) < (then.month, then.day)
  ```

  как в [@Danny W. Adair ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754466/4279).
- если на 28 февраля в обычные годы переносится, то можно просто поправить birthday:

  ```
  import calendar

  if not calendar.isleap(now.year) and birthday.month == 2 and birthday.day == 29:
      birthday = birthday.replace(day=28)
  ```

Легально в разных странах по разному.

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
Пример работы с датой
"""
from datetime import datetime


def parse_age(date, strip):
    """
    Работаем с датой в строке
    :param date: строка даты
    :param strip: строка разделитель по которому будем разбивать строку
    :return: int возраст
    """
    #Разбиваем строку, и берем 3й элемент с индексом 2 
    year = int(date.split(strip)[2])
    now = datetime.now()
    return now.year - year


print(parse_age('31/07/1972 45 years old'.split()[0], '/'))
print(parse_age('31-07-1972 45 years old'.split()[0], '-'))
print(parse_age('31.07.1972 45 years old'.split()[0], '.'))
```

Comment: 1- Возраст может от текущего месяца и дня зависеть, а не только от года. 2- не используйте `str('')`

Comment: Благодарю. По поводу замечания номер 2 поправил.